# Declaring and referencing an 2d array of byte arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, declaration, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2 dimensional array of byte arrays (so, I guess that's a 3d array?) and then write every array stored into it to a file.

I'm doing this because I need to sort the byte arrays I'm receiving through a socket before writing them to a file.

There is a header in the buffer that I'm receiving from the socket which tells me the value in the 2d array that it should be stored (at buffer[0] and buffer[1]) and the total size of the array (at buffer[2] and buffer[3])

I feel like I should be able to do something like this

```
byte[][][] outputbuffer = new byte[(int)buffer[2]][(int)buffer[3]][];
```

to declare the array, and then every time I receive a buffer from the socket,

```
outputbuffer[(int)buffer[0]][(int)buffer[1]][] = buffer;
```

to populate the array, and

```
countera=buffer[2];
counterb=buffer[3];
```

to keep track of the size of the array for when I write it to the file.

Then, to write it to the file,

```
for (i=0;i<countera ;i++ ) {
    for (j=0;j<counterb ;j++ ) {
        file.write(outputbuffer[i][j][]);
        }
    }
```

I get an "illegal start of expression" error when I try to declare an array like this.  Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify all dimensions when you create an array. You haven't specified the last one.

Comment: I changed the declaration to

    byte[][][] outputbuffer = new byte[(int)buffer[2]][(int)buffer[3]][buffer.length];

but I still get an illegal start of expression error when I try to store an array in the array.

    outputbuffer[(int)buffer[0]][(int)buffer[1]][] = buffer;

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use C-style triple pointers, but you can't do it in java. See Ankit Gupta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`byte[][][] outputbuffer = new byte[(int)buffer[2]][(int)buffer[3]][];`

This will not work as array size must be given when creating it. If you do not know size use `ArrayList`
i.e. `ArrayList[][] outputBuffer`

`outputbuffer[i][j][]` should be `Arrays.toString(outputbuffer[i][j])`. [] is used to declare an array, not reference it.

Same applies for `outputbuffer[(int)buffer[0]][(int)buffer[1]][]`, you should update array element by element i.e. `outputbuffer[(int)buffer[0]][(int)buffer[1]][0]`.

Comment: That's helpful, but I'm getting my error when I try to declare the array as well as when I try to reference it.